# What is this 90's anime with a dragon and a sorcerer?

Tags: orphen

Right, so there's this anime I remember watching on Netflix a while back, and I only saw the first few episodes. Upon returning to Netflix now, I can't find it, can't remember it's name, and I want to watch it. Such a prediciment...

But that's where you come in, I guess! Lemme not spare a single detail and perhaps I'll find it yet.

So, first off, it's a 90's medieval anime, starring this sorcerer dude I guess. He's teaching his apprentice magic or something when this big yellow dragon gets summoned and he recognizes it as a friend that had been transformed into previously stated dragon. That's the most prominent thing I can remember though, that the dragon was a friend that had been transformed.

Among other, smaller details, there was this chick who lived in a mansion or something that the sorcerer dude stayed in for a while so he could wait for the dragon or something. She was like, blonde or something.

There was also a scene where the sorcerer was at a bar that was owned by the father/uncle/etc of the apprentice, and he ordered this milkshake, which fell on the ground into this mess, and he used his magic to pick it off the ground and fix the cup and everything, eating it before they could say it was probably dirty from the floor. This scene was in the first episode I believe (Real helpful, I know).

So yeah, I don't know much about it, but the basic facts are:

- 90's Anime.
- Medieval Setting.
- Friend turned into a yellow dragon.
- Main character is a sorcerer.
- That milkshake scene (Because that will TOTALLY narrow it down).

Any help will be much appreciated, happy hunting!

Comment: Which country are you in? Netflix has different lists of shows based on where you reside

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The show you are looking for is called *Orphen* , also known as *Sorcerous Stabber Orphen*

It was aired in 1999

- Main character is a sorcerer -

[image]

- Friend turning into a dragon -

> Krylancelo Finrandi once attended the most prestigious school of sorcery on Kiesalhima continent, the Tower of Fang. He was sent there as a young child from an orphanage, along with another orphan girl called Azalie. Throughout the years, the two were very close, with Azalie becoming more and more powerful and Krylancelo looking up to her as a sister/mother figure and a best friend. It isn't until one day, Azalie's thirst for knowledge and extracurricular experimentation backfire, and she is horribly transfigured into a hideous creature, a dragon-like beast that departs the Tower in an animal fury, leaving Krylancelo behind

[image]

- Milkshake scene:

About 7 minutes into the first episode, the main character spills his milkshake/icecream/parfait thing:

[image]

He then magics it back together again

[image]

Comment: Oh my god, hahahaha, I didn't expect it to be found that quickly! Only one hour or so after I had posted as well. But yeah, that's it, thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, the icecream actually helped me verify it :D  you can mark my answer as accepted if it's definitely correct :)